# Distance/proximity matrix in hierachical clustering

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, hierarchical-clustering

I'm new to Weka and I am trying to do hierachical clustering. I have a symmetric distance/proximity matrix like this:

```
    a      b      c      d 
a   0      0.1    0.3     0.2
b   0.1    0      0.7     0.4
c   0.3    0.7    0       0.9
d   0.2    0.4    0.9     0
```

I want to do hierarchical agglomerative clustering with these instances(a,b,c,d,..). I installed Weka3.6.11 but I couldn't find any part for passing this distance/proximity matrix in ***cluster*** Tab.
can anyone help me?
Is there any easy way in other environments for this purpose? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know how can I do this in weka too!

Comment: Dear Rock, I used a java code for  hierarchical agglomerative clustering.

Comment: Cool. Which one are you using?

Comment: Here it is:  https://github.com/lbehnke/hierarchical-clustering-java

Comment: I see. Thanks. I end up using Weka.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for other environment as well and If you are willing to leave Java, clustering is pretty easy using `scipy` package in python. Eg, you can look at `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`